# How to make xcope in emacs not remove my cscope.out file and regenerate the database

Tags: emacs

I am running emacs 24.3 on ubuntu. I have this in my .emacs file:
    (require 'xcscope)
    (cscope-setup)
    (setq cscope-do-not-update-database t)

I have create cscope.out under /home/mike/mysrc.
And when I open a .c file, I have "set initial directory" in cscope menu. 
but why xcscope delete my cscope.out under /home/mike/mysrc and re create a database when I do a 'find symbol' in cscope manual?

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct variable name? See https://github.com/dkogan/xcscope.el/blob/master/xcscope.el#L548

Comment: There seem to be two packages for cscope. One lives here (https://github.com/vmfhrmfoaj/cscope-el/) and the other is pointed by @angus. `cscope-el` has the option named `cscope-do-not-update-database` but it does **not** have the function `cscope-setup`. So I guess you have mixed up between the two packages try replacing `(setq cscope-do-not-update-database t)` with `(setq cscope-option-do-not-update-database t)`